# Husky, GitHub Desktop commit error: cannot find module yarn.js

Tags: git, yarnpkg, modulenotfounderror, github-desktop, husky

I am working on a project that has Husky dependency.
When I try to commit changes or switch branch on GitHub Desktop, I get this error:

```
2022-11-16T12:18:08.885Z - error: [ui] `git commit -F -` exited with an unexpected code: 1.
stderr:
/c/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/yarn: line 5: cygpath: command not found
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-3.1.2\resources\app\git\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.10.0
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

**OS**: Windows 10 Pro 
**GitHub Desktop**: Version 3.1.2 
**Git**: Version 2.38.0.windows.1

If i use git from Powershell, everything works fine.

Comment: This is the line that catches my eye: `cygpath: command not found`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the problem is, there is no `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-3.1.2\resources\app\git\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js`

My first assumption is that there is no npm initialized in the `git` folder. Let's check:

1- Open Powershell 
2- Type `cd C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-3.1.2\resources\app\git`  to set the directory 
3- Type `explorer .` to view the folder in File Explorer

[image: screenshot from the git folder]

So we see no `node_modules`, `package.json` or `package-lock.json`. This means that npm is not initialized in this current directory.

To add the missing `...\git\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js`:

1- Run `npm init` to initialize npm in the directory. 
2- Run `npm i yarn` to add **yarn** dependency to the current directory.

This way, we have added the missing `...\git\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js` file. 
Now everything works fine!

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer works, but you need to repeat it after every update of GitHub as the path will change (as per version name).
The key here is `cygpath: command not found`. cygpath is shipped with Git and is present in  C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin. Add that to PATH and the problem will be fixed permanently.

Comment: Yes it does require repeating it after every update of GitHub Desktop. I couldn't quite understand how to do your solution, can you update your answer? Where is that PATH that I should add cygpath.exe to?

Comment: Please check this: https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/
I hope I don't need to edit my answer anymore and PATH is explained.